# Сортировка двусвязного списка

Tags: c++

Подскажите как правильно сортировать двусвязный список. Сделал вот такую реализацию, но как вообще правильно нужно сортировать и какие есть варианты сортировки?

```
void List::Sort()
{
    Elem *temp = Head;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        if (temp->data > temp->next->data)
        {
            swap(temp->data, temp->next->data);
            temp = temp->next;
            Sort();
        }
        else
            temp = temp->next; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычно под сортировкой имеется в виду перестановка указателей на узлы списка, а не обмен данных (представьте себе, что копирование данных дорогое). Кроме того, с рекурсией и длиной списка в миллион у вас вполне возможно переполнение стека.

Comment: @Костя Мазур Из вашего вопроса неясно, нужно ли вам написать рекурсивную функцию сортировки, или вас интересуют возможные методы сортировки списков. Если последнее, то вы можете, например, воспользоваться методом вставки вместо пузырьковой. сортировки.

Comment: А это точно нужно? Сколько использовал двусвязный список (или односвязный, тут уж все равно), то имеет смысл при вставке элемента вставлять его в "нужное" место. (то есть список всегда отсортирован)

Comment: @Алексей Саровский: Такой подход имеет смысл только в том случае, если вам действительно нужен список, который "всегда отсортирован".   Если же вам не нужна *постоянная* отсортированность, а нужна лишь отсортированность *в финале*, то ваш вариант эквивалентен сортировке методом простой вставки. А это в общем весьма и весьма неэффективно.

Comment: У @AnT, хороший алгоритм, но можно еще и [так](http://www.williamspublishing.com/PDF/978-5-8459-1650-1/part.pdf ) (раздел 8.7). А вот [это реализация для двусвязного списка](http://pastebin.com/EVwuTAiF) (смотрите list2_sort() в конце файла)

Comment: @avp, если честно мне как новичку очень сложно разобраться в этом примере. Я не понимаю что за параметры принимает эта функция, и зачем их так много если мы работаем с 1 листом?
static void list2_sort(List<T> *list, int(*fcmp)(List<T> *e1, List<T> *e2))

Comment: Тут 2 параметра. Список, который сортируем и *функция* (на самом деле указатель на нее), которая сравнивает 2 элемента списка, так называемый callback (аналогичный callback в известной qsort). Эту функцию вызывает код list2_sort(), когда требуется сравнить элементы сливаемых списков. (ну, Вы пока особо не напрягайтесь, просто почитайте man qsort и посмотрите соответствующие примеры -- разберетесь).

Comment: @avp, тоесть как должен выглядеть вызов этой функции? 
list2_sort(1-параметр это наш лист, а второй какой?);

Comment: Прежде всего (если пока сами еще не разобрались) List2 это структура, которая д.б. встроена в ваши данные и связывает их в список. Допустим, Вы хотите сделать список целых  и тогда объявляете `struct my_data { int data; List2 list_item; };` Делаете список `LIST2_HEAD(my_list);` Добавляете туда данные, скажем, `for(...) { struct my_data *d = malloc(sizeof(*d)); d->data = rand(); list2_add(&(d->list_item), &my_list);}`

Comment: Тогда функция сравнения 2-х data -- `int fcmp (List2 *e1, List2 *e2) { struct my_data *p1 =  list_entry(e1, struct my_data, list_item), *p2 = list_entry(e2, struct my_data, list_item); return p1->data - p2->data; }`, которую передаете в list2_sort `list2_sort(&my_list, fcmp);`  Как видите макрос `list_entry` возвращает адрес (указатель) Вашей структуры по известному указателю на структуру List2 внутри Вашей структуры. Такая техника позволяет включать структуры независимо  в несколько списков (деревьев, хэш-таблиц) одновременно.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Традиционным алгоритмом сортировки для списка - именно списка - является алгоритм MergeSort, построенный на принципе "onion braid" ("косичка из луковиц"). Он прекрасно сортирует односвязные списки, а уж двусвязность списка никакой принципиальной роли в таком алгоритме не играет.

Алгоритм сортирует список путем переназначения ссылок `next` между элементами списка, а не физическим переносом полезных данных из одного элемента в другой. Т.е. все данные, хранимые в элементах списка, сохраняют свое физическое расположение в памяти.

Именно этот алгоритм обычно реализуется в `std::list::sort()`. Собственно ради него шаблону `std::list` и дали свой собственный метод `sort()`.

Алгоритм прост. Он использует в качестве вспомогательного под-алгоритма классический алгоритм слияния двух отсортированный списков в один отсортированный список (я не буду описывать его здесь, ибо это элементарный базовый алгоритм.)

Итак:

1. Заводим `K > 0` "крючков" (с номерами от `0` до `K-1`), на которые мы будем вешать промежуточные подсписки. Число `K` может быть произвольным, его роль станет понятна из дальнейшего описания

   ```
   List hooks[K] = {};
   ```
2. Берем первый узел `node` из исходного списка и вешаем его на крючок `0`, если он свободен (изначально он, разумеется, будет свободен)

   ```
   node->next = nullptr;
   hooks[0] = node;
   ```
3. Берем следующий узел `node` из исходного списка и пытаемся повесить его на крючок `0`. Мы сразу видим, что крючок занят (т.е. `hooks[0] != nullptr`). Тогда мы снимаем с крючка `0` уже подвешенный туда ранее узел `prev_node`. Крючок `0` при этом освобождается)

   ```
   prev_node = hooks[0];
   hooks[0] = NULL;
   ```

   затем соединяем узлы `node` и `prev_node` в сортированный список длины 2

   ```
   if (prev_node->data > node->data)
     std::swap(prev_node, node);

   prev_node->next = node;
   node->next = nullptr;
   ```

   (Я выписал слияние выше явно, но на самом деле его может сделать тот самый под-алгоритм слияния двух отсортированных списков, который я упоминал выше и который мы в таких случаях будем использовать ниже. Просто в данном случае оба сливаемых списка содержат по одному элементу.)

   Далее вешаем этот список длины 2 на крючок `1` (если он свободен)

   ```
   hooks[1] = prev_node;
   ```
4. Продолжаем в том же духе. Берем из входного списка очередной узел и вешаем  его на крючок `0`. Берем из входного списка еще один очередной узел, видим, что крючок номер `0` занят. Сливаем эти узлы в отсортированный список длины 2. Пытаемся повесить его на крючок номер `1`. Видим, что он тоже занят (!). Сливаем два отсортированных списка длины 2 в один отсортированный список длины 4 и вешаем его на крючок `2`. Крючки `0` и `1` становятся свободными.
5. Продолжаем продолжать в том же духе. В каждый момент времени крючок номер `k` будет либо свободен, либо занят отсортированным списком длины 2<sup>k</sup>. Каждый новый элемент из исходного списка либо подвешивается на свободный крючок `0`, либо вызывает движущийся слева-направо по массиву `hooks` каскад слияний и перевешеваний подсписков, пока не будет найден свободный крючок. Списки длины 1 объединяются в списки длины 2, списки длины 2 - в списки длины 4, длины 4 - в 8 и т.д. и т.п.

   Разумеется, каскад перевешиваний должен останавливаться, если достигнут последний элемент массива `hooks`. Те подсписки, которые сумеют добраться до самого последнего элемента массива `hooks`, т.е крючка `K-1`, сливаются в один длинный список и продолжают висеть на крючке `K-1`. Таким образом подсписок на крючке `K-1` может быть длиннее 2<sup>K-1</sup>.
6. Когда исходный список полностью вычитан и развешан по крючкам, просто делаем финальный проход по массиву `hooks` и сливаем все подвешенные на крючках подсписки в один финальный сортированный список.

Величина `K`, как сказано выше, может быть произвольной. Слишком малое значение `K` не сломает алгоритм, но понизит его эффективность. Имеет смысл выбирать `K` примерно равной log<sub>2</sub> от ожидаемого количества элементов во входных списках. Понятно, что на 32-битной платформе нет смысле брать `K` больше, чем 32.

На первый взгляд может показаться не очевидным, что этот алгоритм реализует именно стратегию MergeSort, однако если внимательно рассмотреть выполняемую им последовательность разбиений и слияний, то можно легко видеть, что в обработке фигурируют те же самые подсписки, что в привычном "классическом" MergeSort, просто порядок их обработки несколько иной.

Для работы с *двусвязным* списком можно просто постоянно поддерживать две ссылки `prev` и `next` при линковке элементов друг с другом. Однако, так как этот алгоритм часто перелинковывает элементы списка, возможно более разумным будет в течение всего алгоритма рассматривать список как *односвязный*, т.е. поддерживать только ссылки `next`. А уже в самом конце работы алгоритма, когда формируется финальный отсортированный список (на шаге 5), установить правильные значения ссылок `prev`.

Comment: благодарю за столь подробное обьяснение, но я не могу понять как применить ваш алгоритм к моему коду. Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Костя Мазур: Если вы поняли алгоритм, то "применить его к коду" можно только одним способом: реализовать его. Вот вам пример готовой реализации для односвязного списка: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8069ce4bc6e999c5. От нее за версту разит Си-шными корнями, но у вас и сама задача с такими корнями.

Comment: пока что я не особо разбираюсь в различиях С и С++ и поэтому не можете объяснить что вы подразумеваете под Си-шными корнями?

Comment: @Костя Мазур: Под "Си-шными корнями" я подразумеваю только то, что код, который я привел по ссылке, был получен мною путем быстрой перелицовки моего изначально чисто Си-шного кода во что-то более-менее С++-подобное.

Answer (score 4):

Если говорить применительно к C++ — вот так

```
    std::list<long> list = { 2, 4, 1, 3 };
    list.sort();
```

Если же вы хотите понять, какие в принципе бывают алгоритмы сортировки, — [вот](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), например, неплохой список сортировок со сравнением по разным показателям.

Так как у вас список (то есть, структура данных не предоставляет random access), вам подойдут не все сортировки из списка. Применимы сортировки пузырьком, вставками или выбором.