# Сортировка однонаправленного списка С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, список, односвязный-список

помогите мне отсортировать список по имени, я понятия не имею как его нормально отсортировать.

```
    struct Worker // структура.
{
    string name;
    int rank;
    int yearOfBirth;
    int salary;
    Worker *next;
};
```

Вот что я пока начудил.

```
void printName(Worker* workers, int &size) // функция которая выводит на экран записи отсортированые по имени.
{
    Worker *min_worker = new Worker;
    Worker *time = new Worker;
    Worker *perv = new Worker;
    Worker *current = workers;
    for (int i = 0; workers != NULL; i++) {
        min_worker = workers;
        for (Worker *worker_k = workers; worker_k->next != NULL;) {
            if (min_worker->next->name[0] > worker_k->next->name[0]) {
                min_worker = worker_k;
            }
            perv = worker_k;
            worker_k = worker_k->next;
        }
        if (min_worker != workers) {
            /*swap(array[idx_i], array[min_idx]);*/
            time = min_worker;
            time->next = new Worker;
            current = time;
        }
        workers = workers->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тривиальным решением будет скопировать список в массив, отсортировать массив любым подходящим алгоритмом, после чего снова превратить его в список.

Но для непосредственной сортировки односвязных списков прекрасно подходит алгоритм MergeSort по стратегии снизу-вверх. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433885/182825

Ваш код по-видимому является реализацией SelectionSort. И SelectionSort, и InsertionSort и BubbleSort тоже будут работать на односвязном списке.

Сразу бросаются в глаза, однако, какие-то бессмысленные действия

```
Worker *time = new Worker;
Worker *perv = new Worker;
```

являющиеся очевидными утечками памяти. Зачем вы выделяли эту память?

Comment: Я уже чудил такое что на голову не налезет просто xd. 
Я хотел сохранить ячейку которая указывает на переменную которую надо переставить, и первую ячейку. Ну спасибо вам большое =D