# Связанный список. Как улучшить быструю сортировку?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, linked-list, qsort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int data){
        this->data = data;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

class List {
private:
    Node* root;
    int size;

    void qsortRec(Node* root, int start, int finish){
        int pivot = get((start + finish)/2)->data;
        int s = start;
        int f = finish;

        while(s <= f){
            while(get(s)->data < pivot) s++;
            while(get(f)->data > pivot) f--;
            if(s <= f){
                node_swap(s, f);
                s++;
                f--;
            }
        }

        if(start < f) qsortRec(root, start, f);
        if(s < finish) qsortRec(root, s, finish);
    }

    void node_swap(int i, int j){
        Node* ii = get(i);
        Node* jj = get(j);

        int t = ii->data;
        ii->data = jj->data;
        jj->data = t;
    }

public:
    List(){
        root = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }

    void insert(int data){
        if(root == nullptr) root = new Node(data);
        else {
            Node* curr = root;
            while(curr->next != nullptr) curr = curr->next;
            curr->next = new Node(data);
        }
        size++;
    }

    void display(){
        Node* curr = root;
        while(curr != nullptr){
            cout << curr->data << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    void qsort(){
        qsortRec(root, 0, size - 1);
    }

    Node* get(const int index){
        int count = 0;
        Node* curr = root;
        while(curr != nullptr){
            if(count == index)
                return curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            count++;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main(){
    clock_t start = clock();

    List* list = new List();

    list->insert(4);
    list->insert(9);
    list->insert(1);
    list->insert(0);
    list->insert(7);

    cout << "Initial: ";
    list->display();

    list->qsort();

    cout << endl << "Sorted: ";
    list->display();

    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << endl << (end - start) << "ms" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас метод доступа с элементу реализуется с помощью цикла от начала списка до конца. Скорость вашего алгоритма становится квадратичной из-за этого. Пользоваться нужно не `get`, а сделать относительную функцию поиска.

```
...
private :
  // по относительному индексу с from
  Node* get(Node* from , int const index);
};

Node* List::get(Node* from , int const index) {
        int count = 0;
        Node* curr = from;
        while(curr != nullptr) {
            if(count == index) 
                return curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            count++;        }
        return nullptr;    }
```

Дальше у рекурсивной функции `qsortRec` аргумент `root` сделать указателем на `Node` с индексом `start` и именем `firstNode`. Вы всё равно этим аргументом не пользуетесь. И использовать относительный `get` примерно так:

```
int pivot = get(firstNode,(start + finish)/2)->data;
while(get(firstNode,s-start)->data < pivot) 
    s++;
while(get(firstNode,f-start)->data > pivot) 
    f--;
node_swap(firstNode,s,f); // ! тоже новый относительный метод 
if(start < f)
    qsortRec(firstNode, 0, f-start);
if(s < finish)
    qsortRec(get(firstNode,s-start), 0, finish-start);
```

После отладки убрать аргумент `start` , он всегда будет нулевым.

---

Для списков быстрая сортировка не подходит. Если можно, то **нужно** использовать сортировку слиянием. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Comment: У quicksort для связного списка, собственно, только одна проблема -- скорость выбора pivot элемента. Если в качестве него брать первый из списка, то остальное легко

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример quicksort для односвязного списка структур, аналогичных вашему примеру.

Данная программа выбирает в качестве разделяющего (pivot) элемента первый в списке и в среднем (при случайных данных) должна работать за время порядка `N * log(N)`.

В отличие от вашего примера здесь данные не перемещаются по узлам списка,   перестановка элементов  производится изменением указателей на следующий. Обычно именно такой способ требуют от любой сортировки списка, т.е. *неизменность адреса данных* после сортировки.

```
struct list_item {
  struct list_item *next;
  int v;
};

struct list_hdr {
  struct list_item *head, *tail;
  size_t size;
};


void
add_item_lst (struct list_item *p, struct list_hdr *h)
{
  if (h->tail) 
    h->tail->next = p;
  else
    h->head = p;
  h->tail = p;
  h->size++;
}

void
lst_qsort (struct list_hdr *h)
{
  //  printf("==> "); print_lst(h);

  if (h->head == h->tail)
    return;
  struct list_hdr llt = {0}, leq = {0}, lgt = {0};

  // use first list item as pivot
  // move it to `leq` list
  leq.head = leq.tail = h->head;
  leq.size = 1;
  h->head = h->head->next;

  // divide list to 3 parts
  while (h->head) {
    struct list_item *p = h->head;
    h->head = h->head->next;  // remove item

    // add it to `llt`, `leq` or `lgt` lists
    if (p->v < leq.head->v)
      add_item_lst(p, &llt);
    else if (p->v > leq.head->v)
      add_item_lst(p, &lgt);
    else
      add_item_lst(p, &leq);
  };

  // for speed reason, I not set pointer to next in the tail items
  // now correct them
  if (llt.tail)
    llt.tail->next = 0;
  leq.tail->next = 0;
  if (lgt.tail)
    lgt.tail->next = 0;

  //  print_lst(&llt);
  //  print_lst(&leq);
  //  print_lst(&lgt);
  //  puts("======");

  // sort by parts
  lst_qsort(&llt);
  lst_qsort(&lgt);

  // merge parts to source list
  if (llt.head) {
    h->head = llt.head;
    llt.tail->next = leq.head;
  } else 
    h->head = leq.head;
  h->tail = leq.tail;
  if (h->tail->next = lgt.head) 
    h->tail = lgt.tail;

  //  printf("<== "); print_lst(h);
}
```

Следует заметить, что выбор первого элемента для разделения списка не является достаточно хорошим (другие же сильно замедляют программу). Поэтому на практике для сорировки связного списка вместо quicksort надо использовать вариант [mergesort](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433885/232) (рекомендую зайти по ссылке и для упражнения написать свою реализацию).