# Функция swap для сортировки односвязного списка

Tags: c

Как реализовать функцию `swap` для сортировки односвязного списка?

Моя структура:

```
struct prog
{
    char name[80];
    unsigned int kol;
    double time1;
    double time2;

    struct prog* next;
};
```

Мой код сортировки (сортировал относительно переменной `kol`):

```
void zad6(struct prog* head)
{
    int swapped, i;
    struct prog* ptr1;
    struct prog* lptr = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = head;
        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->kol > ptr1->next->kol)
            {
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    } while (swapped);
}
```

Вот моя функция `swap`:

```
void swap(struct prog* a, struct prog* b)
{
     // что тут написать?
}
```

Comment: В вашем (неправильном) варианте сортровки списка можно перемещать данные между элементами списка, сохраняя указатели. `void swap(struct prog* a, struct prog* b) { struct prog t; struct prog *a_next, *b_next; a_next = a->next; b_next = b->next; t = *a; *a = *b; *b = t; a->next = a_next; b->next = b_next;}`

Comment: ну как, сортировка получилась?

Comment: avp, да спасибо все работает

Comment: @avp, мне нравится этот пользователь с односвязным списком. Он уже наделал 100500 учёток и после каждого вопроса закрывает их...

Comment: @0andriy, боится чего-то, наверное считает, что так его не отследят

Answer (score 1):

А вот так правильно (в рамках того же алгоритма, делающего перестановки пока переставляется) программировать сортировку списка.
Правильно в смысле эффективности.

По сути, эффективная сортировка списка должна менять порядок его элементов (изменять указатели на следующий в структурах данных),
а не копировать содержимое одной области памяти в другую. Это особенно актуально, если в элементах списка хранится много данных (например, несколько килобайт) или на эти данные есть указатели из других структур данных.

```
struct prog *
sort_list (struct prog *head)
{
  int swp;

  do {
    swp = 0;
    struct prog **prev = &head;

    for (struct prog *p = head; p && p->next; p = p->next) {
      if (p->kol > p->next->kol) {
        // SWAP;
        struct prog *t = p->next,
          *u = p->next->next;

        p->next = u;
        t->next = p;
        *prev = t;
        swp++;
      }
      prev = &(p->next);
    }
  } while (swp);

  return head;
}
```

использование:

```
struct prog *list = make_list();
  ...
list = sort_list(list);
```

Замечу, что длинные списки сортировать таким алгоритмом весьма не эффективно. С хорошей сортировкой списков (сложность N log(N)) можно ознакомиться [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433885/232).