# Что нужно написать в функции чтобы сортировала ключи

Tags: c++

```
void Sort_travelers_list (Travelers **list, int (*cmpf)(Travelers *s1, Travelers *s2));
```

которая при сравнении элементов будет вызывать передаваемую ей функцию-компаратор cmpf

```
int cmpf_ticket (Travelers *s1, Travelers *s2) {
  return s1->ticket_code - s2->ticket_code;
}
 
int cmpf_lastname (Travelers *s1, Travelers *s2) {
  int rc = 0;
  if (s1->lastname < s2->lastname)
    rc = -1;
  else if (s1->lastname > s2->lastname)
    rc = 1;
  return rc;
}


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Travelers
{
    int ticket_code;
    string lastname;
    int numberofthings;
    int luggage_weight;
    Travelers* Next;
};

Travelers* Head = 0;
struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    Date* Next;
};
Date* Head2 = 0;
struct Date2 {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    Date* Next;
};
Date* Head3 = 0;
void Insert_Traveler(Travelers** list, Travelers* t, unsigned int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0 || *list == 0) {
        t->Next = *list;
        *list = t;
    }
    else if (pos == 0) {
        t->Next = *list;
        *list = t;
    }
    else {
        Travelers* p = *list;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
            if (i == pos - 1)
                break;
        t->Next = p->Next;
        p->Next = t;
    }
}
Travelers* Choose_Travelers(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos)
{
    while (list && pos)
    {
        list = list->Next;
        --pos;
    }

    return list;
}
Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore1(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos) {
    return Choose_Travelers(list, pos + 1);
}
Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore2(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos) {
    return Choose_Travelers(list, pos - 1);
}
int Location(Travelers* list, string key) {
    Travelers* p = list;
    unsigned int n = 0;
    for (; p; n++, p = p->Next) {
        if (p->lastname == key) break;
    }
    return n;
}
Travelers* Delete_Traveler(Travelers** list, unsigned int pos)
{
    Travelers* d = 0;

    if (pos == 0) {
        d = *list;
        *list = d->Next;
    }
    else {
        Travelers* p = *list;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
            if (i == pos - 1) {
                d = p->Next;
                p->Next = d->Next;
                break;
            }
    }

    return d;
}

void Print_Travelers(Travelers* list)
{
    for (Travelers* p = list; p; p = p->Next)
        cout << "code: " << p->ticket_code
        << "  " << p->lastname
        << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
        << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
        << '\n';
    cout << '\n';
}
void Print_Date(Date* list) {
    for (Date* p = list; p; p = p->Next)
        cout << "day: " << p->day
        << " month: " << p->month
        << " year: " << p->year
        << '\n';
    cout << '\n';
}
void Unite_Date(Date* head1, Date* head2)
{
    Date* p = head1;
    while (p->Next != NULL)
        p = p->Next;
    p->Next = head2;
}
Date* Find_Date(Date* list, size_t pos)
{
    if (pos == 0 || !list)
        return list;

    while (list->Next && pos)
    {
        list = list->Next;
        --pos;
    }
    return list;
}

void Insert_Date(Date** list, Date* pos, Date* item)
{
    if (!pos)
    {
        item->Next = *list;
        *list = item;
    }
    else
    {
        item->Next = pos->Next;
        pos->Next = item;
    }
}

void Insert_Date(Date** list, Date* t, size_t pos)
{
    Insert_Date(list, Find_Date(*list, pos), t);
}
void SortTravelersList(Travelers** list, int (*cmpf)(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2));
int cmpf_ticket(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2) {
    return s1->ticket_code - s2->ticket_code;
}

int cmpf_lastname(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2) {
    int rc = 0;
    if (s1->lastname < s2->lastname)
        rc = -1;
    else if (s1->lastname > s2->lastname)
        rc = 1;
    return rc;
}
int main()
{

    Date* q = new Date;
    q->day = rand() % 30;
    q->month = rand() % 12;
    q->year = 2021;
    Insert_Date(&Head2, q, 1);
    Print_Date(Head2);
    Date* w = new Date;
    w->day = rand() % 30;
    w->month = rand() % 12;
    w->year = 2021;
    Insert_Date(&Head3, w, 1);
    Print_Date(Head3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char nm[10];
        Travelers* p = new Travelers;
        p->ticket_code = rand() % 1000;
        sprintf_s(nm, "tr_%d", i);
        p->lastname = nm;
        p->numberofthings = rand() % 5 + 1;
        p->luggage_weight = (rand() % 10 + 1) * p->numberofthings;

        Insert_Traveler(&Head, p, i);
    }

    cout << "list of travelers\n";
    Print_Travelers(Head);

    cout << "delete some travelers\n";
    Travelers* p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, 9);
    if (p) {
        cout << "delete as pos " << 9 << "  "
            << "code: " << p->ticket_code
            << "  " << p->lastname
            << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
        delete p;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, i);
        if (p) {
            cout << "delete as pos " << i << "  "
                << "code: " << p->ticket_code
                << "  " << p->lastname
                << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
                << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
                << '\n';
            delete p;
        }
    }

    cout << "------\n";
    cout << "\nlist of travelers after deletions\n";
    Print_Travelers(Head);
    int pos;
    cout << "Choose index" << endl;
    cin >> pos;
    Travelers* k = Choose_Travelers(Head, pos);
    if (!k)
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "code: " << k->ticket_code
            << "  " << k->lastname
            << " nth: " << k->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << k->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
    }
    cout << "Enter a key you want to choose" << endl;
    string key;
    cin >> key;
    int t = Location(Head, key);
    cout << t << endl;
    int poss;
    cout << "Choose index" << endl;
    cin >> poss;
    Travelers* e = Choose_NextAndBefore1(Head, poss);
    if (!e)
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "code: " << e->ticket_code
            << "  " << e->lastname
            << " nth: " << e->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << e->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
    }
    Travelers* b = Choose_NextAndBefore2(Head, poss);
    if (!b)
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "code: " << b->ticket_code
            << "  " << b->lastname
            << " nth: " << b->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << b->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
    }
    Unite_Date(Head2, Head3);
    Print_Date(Head2);
    SortTravelersList(&Head, cmpf_ticket);
    Print_Travelers(Head);
}
```

Comment: Что такое у вас `list`? Массив указателей? тогда просто напишите `sort(list, list+N, cmpf)`, где N - число элементов. И еще - ваша функция сравнения **не** меняет передаваемые элементы - ну так сделайте же ее от констант, типа `cmpf_ticket (const Travelers *s1, const Travelers *s2)`

Comment: добавил весь код

Comment: можете написать я что-то не очень понимаю как

Comment: А, раз список - там возни много, то, что я написал, не годится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, не слишком эффективная (сложность *O(N^2)*), но простая в реализации сортировка односвязного списка вставками.
(по настоящему хороший метод сорировки списка описан  в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433885/232))

Идея состоит в том, что мы последовательно исключаем элементы  из исходного списка и последовательно просматривая новый (сортированный) список вставляем их в нужное место.

Потом просто присваиваем новый список старому.

```
void Sort_travelers_list (Travelers **list,
                          int (*cmpf)(Travelers *s1, Travelers *s2))
{
  Travelers *srt = 0, *t;

  if ((srt = *list)) {
    *list = (*list)->Next;
    srt->Next = 0;
    while (t = (*list)) {
      *list = (*list)->Next;

      if (cmpf(t, srt) < 0) {
        t->Next = srt;
        srt = t;
      } else {
        Travelers *p = srt;
        while (p->Next) {
          if (cmpf(t, p->Next) < 0) {
            t->Next = p->Next;
            p->Next = t;
            break;
          }
          p = p->Next;
        }
        if (p->Next == 0) {
          t->Next = 0;
          p->Next = t;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  *list = srt;
}
```

Этот вариант не обеспечивает [устойчивую сортировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Если требуется устойчивость, то замените опреатор сравнения с `(cmpf(t, p->Next) < 0)` на **`(cmpf(t, p->Next) <= 0)`** (такой вариант при большом числе одинаковых ключей будет работать несколько медленнее).